# Query with difficult conditions in the project using mptt

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-mptt

I have some mptt model:

```
class Locations(MPTTModel):
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    type = models.ForeignKey('LocationTypes')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Some models related with it:

```
class Building(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.ForeignKey('Locations')
```

And QuerySet like this:

```
building_list = Building.objects.filter(title__icontains='house')
```

I know some "Location" "id", but not directly related to Building, one of ancestors.
What better way to left in building_list, only those elements the is location one of descendants(not necessarily direct) of this "Location"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get descendants list if you know location id with function `get_descendants`:

```
location = Location.objects.get(pk="some_location_id")
descendants = location.get_descendants().values_list('id', flat=True)
building_list = Building.objects.filter(title__icontains='house',
                                        location__in=descendants)
```